# Disable specific shortcut in hyper-v virtual macine

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v, virtual-desktop

I am using Windows as my main os and also running a certain version of Windows as virtual machine in hyper-v. I want to run the vm connection in full screen in a specific virtual desktop while having option to switch different virtual desktops. Is there anyway I can disable virtual desktop related shortcut in my vm so I can achieve what I want??

Comment: Unclear. Can you give more details?

Comment: What part is unclear to you??

Comment: Well, everything.

Comment: I want to run my main os programs in virtual desktop 1 and in virtual desktop 2 I want to run windows in side a hyper-v in full screen. So I want the ability to switch between them using keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Where would you be entering these keyboard shortcuts? Guest or host?

Comment: In both, the question is about switching back and forth between them using keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Open Hyper-V manager and click on "Hyper-V Settings" in the right panel. In the "User" section of the settings window, click on "Keyboard". From there you can control how the windows key combos are handled.